# Need help locating a mistake in a single code line

Tags: c, syntax

```
void find_best_match(char*currword, char(*)[]chosen_dict ,char*newWord,int length_of_dict)
```

I get "expected "," ,";" or ")" before "chosen_dict" " . I've revised the syntax multiple times , but can't locate the error. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to declare `chosen_dict` as?

Comment: The `[]` comes after the name `chosen_dict`, not before.

Answer (score 3):

This does not make any sense:

```
char(*)[]chosen_dict
```

A correct declaration would be

```
char(*chosen_dict)[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Downvoter, if you can prove this is correct, I will accept it.

Comment: +1 for remove unnecessary downvote

Comment: I noticed recently that people downvote more often - even correct answers. I don't understand why...

Comment: @Jack can I share some of my answers that were downvoted with you so you can remove the unnecessary downvotes? Also, keep in mind that 90% of questions on SO can be answered by pasting a line of code that is incorrect and saying it doesn't make sense. Personally, I don't see how **only** this piece of information can be helpful to anyone.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore If you have correct (on-topic) answers with a score < 0, feel free to share them and I would be glad to upvote them. And that's what I usually do in such situation because SO has to remain a place of fairness. In the particular case of this answer, the question was: *Need help locating a mistake* and *can't locate the error*. You can find the answer is short but the thing is, it correctly answers the question. Moreover, it was downvoted to -1 as soon as I entered the answer. This really didn't encourage me to expand my answer and so it remains a short answer.

Comment: Correct, but seeing how the op obviously doesn't have a clue, you could have given him the correct syntax. Nonetheless, I admit I was hasty in downvoting (didn't read the question well enough to see he was only asking for the problematic code, not the fix), and I apologize for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

The pointer to an unknown-sized array is:

```
char (*chosen_dict)[]
```

Some people find the "spiral rule" helpful for understanding the declaration. Others prefer typedefs, and others yet just use `cdecl` to figure this stuff out.

As long as you don't need to declare arrays of function pointers to functions taking pointers to arrays in one line, you should be fine.